semisimple module and jacobson radical
Exercise from Hungerford IX 3.8:
Let $A$ be a (possibly nonunitary) module over a left Artinian ring $R$ such that $Ra \neq 0$ for all nonzero $a \in A$, and let $J = J(R)$. Then if $J(R)A = 0$ then $A$ is semisimple.
From the definition of semisimple, it is enough to show for every submodule of A, it is a direct summand of A.
Here is a hint from the exercise:

If $R$ has an identity and $A$ is an $R$-module, then there are submodules $B$ and $C$ of $A$ such that $B$ is unitary, $RC = 0$ and $A = B \oplus C$.

Let $A_1$ be another $R$-module, with $A_1 = B_1 \oplus C_1$ ($B_1$ unitary, $RC_1 = 0$). If $f: A \rightarrow A_1$ is an $R$-module homomorphism then $f(B) \subseteq B_1$ and $f(C) \subseteq C_1$.


Can someone help me how to use this hint?
